How to find out, whether Macros are defined or not?
In the Linux kernel source code I often see preprocessor directives like:
#ifdef CONFIG_RETHUNK

In general, how can I know, whether these Macros have been defined or not? Because it influences the code that gets executed further down.

At least if you are using standard Ubuntu kernels, you can check the configuration by examining the config files in the /boot directory - for example
$ grep CONFIG_RETHUNK /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_RETHUNK=y

